# Draw in the target viewport

Tags: c#, xna, viewport

few days ago, i asked a question about "how to display in a second viewport without redrawing everything".  One of the answers was "you should use a renderTarget2D and give a Rectangle source to the spritebatch", this solution is without `Matrix` camera.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(
    TheRenderTarget2D, 
    TheViewportTarget.Bounds, 
    TheRectangleSourceFromTheRenderTarget2D, 
    Color.White);
```

That works very fine, but i lose a lot of render quality (because of my game zoom and some other things).

The question is : How to draw in the second viewport with `camera.transform()` to keep the quality, with zoom.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Do you set the size of your render targets to match the size of your viewports?  Rephrased, are your rendered scenes losing "quality" due to scaling?

Comment: @Seth The only way (i know) to zoom without Matrix camera, is to reduce the source Rectangle (That's why the quality is not so good yes). That's why i would like to use a Matrix camera to keep the quality :x

Comment: Sure.  So, would you say you are asking "how to implement zoom?"  If so, then your question isn't really appropriate for SO.  

But really, all you need to do is study the XNA `Matrix` functions documentation.  Here's one that will help the most.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195667(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

Comment: @seth Thx for your comments. But i already know how to use matrix and zoom. I just changed the code to use Rectangle cameras instead of Matrix cameras. I have to learn how to use Matrix camera with RenderTarget2D (to display on 2 differents viewport with 2 cameras)

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood which part of your question made your goal impossible.  You know how to use a 3D camera; you just want to use it only once.  That's exactly the problem.  You must draw your scene twice, using two different camera settings.

Comment: @SethBattin Ok, so, i have to make 2 cameras, 2 viewports. Can you give me a example on How to draw scene1 with camera1 in the 1st viewport, and draw scene2 with camera 2 in the second viewport ? (as answer please, to give you the points you deserve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it :

```
    Graphics.Device = viewport1;
    spriteBatch.Begin(,,,,,Camera1.transformation);
    DrawScene();
    spriteBatch.End();

    Graphics.Device = viewport2;
    spriteBatch.Begin(,,,,,Camera2.transformation);
    DrawScene();
    spriteBatch.End();
```